# RVM Ruby with TK installation (OSX)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to install Ruby with TK support.

Using RVM, I did this:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --enable-shared --enable-pthread
```

The installation appears to work fine, and I can see something called

```
.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/tk/tcltklib.c
```

which I assume is the library I need?

I then try to run

```
require 'tk'
```

in irb, but get the error message

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- tk
```

Any ideas?

### Update: Fixed!

If anyone is interested in the complete list of steps for a Ruby upgrade to 2.0.0 with TK support on OSX, this is what I did:

Install RVM for Ruby -

```
\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

Install TK from ActiveTcl - http://www.activestate.com/activetcl

Run

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl
```

Fire up irb and check the TK installation was successful with

```
require 'tk'
```

Comment: What version of OSX are you using? On my end, no luck with 10.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RVM disables tk/tcl by default (problems on OS X), you need to tell ruby (via rvm) you want tk/tcl:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl
```

Answer (score 3):

First, install ActiveState's ActiveTCL from [here](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). Then, reinstall Ruby with this command:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --enable-pthread
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still gave me the same error. I had to use the --with-tk --with-tcl flags as per mpapis' answer.
+1 for pointing to the ActiveTCL installation though.