# Ruby Core Dump On Requiring TK

Tags: ruby

I tried to use Ruby's TK library today, and it failed miserably, spitting out a nice long core dump.

I'm not sure what I could have done wrong, as I double checked that TK was installed, and even went so far as to reinstall it. I also tried two different versions of Ruby, 2.0.0 and 1.9.3.

The code I tried to execute was simply:

```
require 'tk'
```

Here's the core dump on pastebin. Hopefully that will help narrow it down.

http://pastebin.com/LqZ7B8kK

My system details are as follows:

- OS: Manjaro Linux, x86_64
- Ruby: 1.9.3 and 2.0.0
- Using RVM
- TK installed

I'd rather not use a different GUI library, as the others seem to be less cross-platform.

Finally, I noticed that StackOverflow doesn't have a `tk` tag. Someone with enough reputation points might want to create that and get the badge for it. :D

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately pastebin seems to be down right now, so I can't help much, have you enabled tk on your rvm installation? apparently it's disabled by default: [RVM Ruby with TK installation (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113143/rvm-ruby-with-tk-installation-osx)

the relevant code snippet is

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl
```

for ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Also there appears to be a tk tag on the link given.

Comment: Thanks for the help, man. It still segfaults when try to run the code though. :/

On the plus side, Pastebin seems to be back up.