# error occuring when loading tk library

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I have been trying to get tk to work on my machine for sometime now and for some strange it does not seem to work very well.

Any help would be appreciated. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113143/rvm-ruby-with-tk-installation-osx) instructions but still had no luck

[image]

Please right click on the image and view it in a new tab (I think it is much legible that way)

**Solved**

If anybody is having problems, you can try this!

```
gem install tk_as_gem -- --without-X11 --with-X11-include=/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers --with-tcltk-version=8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Install [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl)
2. Run `rvm install 2.0.0 --with-tcl-dir=/path/to/ActiveTcl --enable-pthread`