# Uninstall Active TCL Mac

Tags: macos, tcl, activetcl

I am trying to uninstall Active TCL on my Mac and the provided code from the website does not work. I am receiving errors saying not a directory. When I look into the file path that the code gives me I can manually find but it does not work. Is there any other way to get rid of this?

Below is the provided code:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/<version>/Resources/Scripts/uninstall
$ sudo ./uninstall
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/Resources/Scripts/
$ sudo ./uninstall
sudo: ./uninstall: command not found
$ ls -al uninstall 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  6868 Oct 26  2013 uninstall
```

uninstall ain't executable.

```
$ sudo chmod a+x uninstall
$ sudo ./uninstall
```

Then a Tcl icon appeared in my Dock, and when I clicked on that, a dialog box popped up asking:

> Confirm you want to delete all Tcl 8.6 files?

Comment: Same problem. This solution works. Active state does leave Teapot and some other files behind.

Comment: There are some additional instructions necessary if you use MacPorts instead of Homebrew. First, you'll need to edit the shebang line of the `uninstall` script. By default, it says `#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6` and you'll need to change it to `#!/opt/local/bin/tclsh8.6`. Also, if it complains something like `can't find package Tk` then just run `sudo port install tk`. Everything else should work as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. You may try it.

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts \
sudo ./uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of failed **sudo ./uninstall** command, fix the permission with **sudo chmod 755 ./uninstall**. Then uninstall command will execute.

Source: https://community.activestate.com/node/9010