# Failing to load Ruby's tk on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, graphics, rubygems, tk-toolkit

I am really new to Ruby and I need to use this library for a specific GUI project. I am using:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS;
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

My problem is similar to the one [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077123/not-able-to-load-tk-in-ruby/57821019#57821019) person described a few months ago. I have tried the solution posted on that SO page which is based on [this](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-ruby-tk-bindings-gem-on-ubuntu/) blog post.

After running:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

And:

```
sudo gem install tk
```

I get the following error message:

```
    Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tk:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.4.0/ext/tk
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20210424-11015-1mre8d0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/tk-0.4.0/gem_make.out
```

This error message is different from the one described in the [blog post](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-ruby-tk-bindings-gem-on-ubuntu/) which is:

```
$ gem install tk
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tk:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
# ...
Search tcl.h
checking for tcl.h... no
Search tk.h
checking for tk.h... no
Search Tcl library............*** extconf.rb failed ***
# ...
Warning:: cannot find Tcl library. tcltklib will not be compiled (tcltklib is disabled on your Ruby. That is, Ruby/Tk will not work). Please check configure options.

Can't find proper Tcl/Tk libraries. So, can't make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.
If you have Tcl/Tk libraries on your environment, you may be able to use them with configure options (see ext/tk/README.tcltklib).

The gem provides many switches for specifying the configuration parameters, however, the related parameters (--with-tk-lib and --with-tcl-lib) don’t yield the desired effect (actually, any effect at all).

The workaround, originally found in a Ruby forum is to symlink the libraries to the paths where the extension expects
```

Then, after running:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcl8.5/tclConfig.sh /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tk8.5/tkConfig.sh /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/
```

I get this (probably because I tried the same steps before):

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/libtk8.5.so.0': File exists
```

Finally, running the last step does **not** work:

```
sudo gem install tk
```

And the terminal returns the following error message:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tk:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.4.0/ext/tk
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20210424-21301-8u83wl.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.4.0 for inspection.
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This tutorial helped me solve the problem: https://dev.to/kojix2/installing-ruby-tk-on-ubuntu-1d86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog post](https://dev.to/kojix2/installing-ruby-tk-on-ubuntu-1d86) solved the problem.

After running:

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

And installing Ruby/Tk gem:

```
gem install tk -- --with-tcltkversion=8.6 \
--with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--enable-pthread
```

Everything was solved.

Comment: Yes, the -dev parts usually install the .h files that the configure script tries to find. Many debian/ubuntu newcomers don't know that yet. Once you know that, the only thing that is typically left is to find the names of the packages, then install these and you are good to go. (All these options to "gem install" are normally not needed actually; I always compile tcl and tk into the /usr/ prefix, and then "gem install tk" works as-is. I assume the above may be necessary because debian tends to put things into particular directories, which is IMO unnecessary.)