# How to create a Calendar widget in Ruby TK

Tags: ruby, calendar, widget, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a calendar widget in Ruby Tk with the following code:

```rb
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/iwidgets'

DEBUG = []

begin
    root = TkRoot.new {title 'Ruby/Tk Calendar'}

    cal = Tk::Iwidgets::Calendar.new(root) {
       outline 'black'
       weekdaybackground 'gray90'
       weekendbackground 'white'
       command {p cal.get}
    }
    cal.pack('pady'=>10)
    cal.show('11/1/2006')

    # Set initial window geometry; i.e., size and placement.
    win_w, win_h = 250, 195
    # root.minsize(win_w, win_h)
    win_lf = (root.winfo_screenwidth - win_w) / 2
    root.geometry("#{win_w}x#{win_h}+#{win_lf}+50")

    # Set resize permissions.
    root.resizable(false, false)

    # Make Cmnd+Q work as expected.
    root.bind('Command-q') {Tk.root.destroy}

    Tk.mainloop
ensure
    puts DEBUG unless DEBUG.empty?
end
```

However, I get the following messages:

**can't find package Itk (RuntimeError)**

**TkPackage can't find package Itk (RuntimeError)**

I've already installed the tcl package but still not working. I'm using Fedora 31 with ruby 2.6.5.

Comment: Please include the output of `ruby -e "require 'tk'; p Tk::TK_PATCHLEVEL"`.

Comment: FWIW, using my old but trusty Tk (version 8.5.12) and Ruby (version 2.2.5p319) combination, your code fails on `require 'tkextlib/iwidgets'` on a different package, saying: `TkPackage can't find package Itcl`.

Comment: FWIW, the "Modern Best Practices" section (and its "Tk Extensions" subsection) of the TkDocs tutorial's [Introduction](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/intro.html) page discourages the use of iWidgets. It's the only place in the tutorial which mentions it.

Comment: Did you install an iwidgets package for Fedora 31? I found one [here](http://pkgs.org/download/iwidgets).

Comment: Web searching "can't find package Itk" yields this bug report: [ITK cant be found after installed](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1706553). Does that help?

Comment: Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16114308), please install [ActiveState's ActiveTCL](http://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/downloads/) (free of charge). [Note](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/pkg/) it contains IWidgets. Then reinstall Ruby.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell the output: "8.6.8" I've already installed active tcl, one detail is that I have to use "rvm use system" to run succefully the tk library. What is the best way to install ruby? Also, when I try to install iwidgets package I get the following output: " Package iwidgets-4.0.2-25.fc31.noarch already installed".

Comment: What are the outputs of `$ rvm use system; ruby -v` and `$ rvm use default; ruby -v`?

Comment: Since you're already using `rvm`, that's a fine way to install Ruby. ActiveState's ActiveTCL obviates any need for the iwidgets RPM package.

Comment: Three years ago, Ruby's Tk adapters were [moved](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8539#note-10) into a gem. So, to use them in your newly-installed (via `rvm`) Ruby, you have to do `$ rvm use default; gem install tk`.

Comment: Assuming ActiveTCL is correctly installed, then do `$ rvm reinstall 2.6.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16114828/1136063).

Comment: After installing Ruby 2.7.0, I can see that `$ gem install tk` says "Tcl/Tk8.6 is not supported...it will not work correctly." Therefore, no Ruby can succeed with the ActiveTcl version (8.6.8) you currently have installed. Instead, you must replace it with ActiveTcl version 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will install the latest release of Ruby (at the time of writing), along with the latest compatible version of Tcl.

Note: after installing Ruby 2.7.0, `$ gem install tk` says "Tcl/Tk8.6 is not supported[;] it will not work correctly." So, instead we must limit our use of Tcl to version 8.5. We will do this by installing ActiveTcl version 8.5.

These steps are for Debian Stretch—so, for Fedora 31, YMMV. :)

Create some directories:

```sh
$ mkdir ~/install
$ mkdir ~/install/temp
$ mkdir ~/progra
```

Using a web browser, download [ActiveTcl 8.5](http://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/) from ActiveState. Then, install it:

```sh
$ pushd ~/install/temp
$ tar zxf ~/Downloads/ActiveTcl-8.5*.tar.gz
$ cd ActiveTcl-8.5*
$ ./install.sh
```

Answer its installation questions:

```
Please specify the installation directory.
Path [/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5]: ~/progra/ActiveTcl-8.5

Please specify the directory for the demos.
Path [~/progra/ActiveTcl-8.5/demos]: 

Please specify the runtime installation directory.
Path [~/progra/ActiveTcl-8.5]:
```

```sh
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/progra/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export MANPATH="$HOME/progra/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/man:$MANPATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Install some system packages which are required by `rvm`:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install curl dirmngr gnupg
```

Install [rvm](https://rvm.io) (the Ruby enVironment Manager) by following these steps, according to its [instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install):

```sh
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
$ echo '# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*' >> ~/.bashrc
$ exit
```

Check and use `rvm`:

```sh
$ type rvm | head -n 1 # It should say, 'rvm is a function'.
$ rvm list known
$ rvm install 2.7.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl
```

Install a system package required by the Tk gem:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Install the Tk gem and check the Tk installation:

```sh
$ gem install tk
$ ruby -W0 -e "require 'tk'; p Tk::TK_PATCHLEVEL"
$ ruby -W0 -e "require 'tk'; require 'tkextlib/iwidgets'; p 'ok'"
```

Now, when I run your program, I see a calendar widget.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did all the steps and it works!!